# Import Firebase auth in Angular not found

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

```
 import { auth } from 'firebase/app'; // not compiling
```

raises linking error:

> "export 'auth' was not found in 'firebase/app'"

versions:  Angular: 11.1.0, rxjs@6.6.3, firebase@8.2.5, firebase-tools@7.16.2

---

I uninstalled @angularfire2, @types/firebase - I thought they could be causing this error,
Im pretty new to angular and firebase, and trying to make the firebase google authentication to work, please help!

---

Comment: try with 'import auth = firebase.auth'

Comment: where should i try it?  instead of "import { auth } from 'firebase/app';" ?

Comment: @angularfire2 is actually deprecated. Why not use the official angular lib for this? https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/auth/getting-started.md

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you import your all firebase confing in environment (whatever you want import thus include it in write way).

**environment.ts**

```js
export const environment = {
  production: false,
   firebaseConfig : {
    apiKey: "*****************",
    authDomain: "a**aa**.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "social-43-23-1212",
    storageBucket: "social-app-df**131.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "2234gsesert",
    appId: "**********************",
    measurementId: "345334535"
  }
};
```

Now add firebase in app.module.ts

```js
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@NgModule({
import:[
   AngularFireModule.initializeApp  
   (environment.firebaseConfig, 'application'),>
  ]
});
```

Comment: hi, thank you, i did that, and still the same error remains..

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
import {firebase} from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/auth';
```

From [here](https://github.com/AnthonyNahas/ngx-auth-firebaseui/commit/73ca9b986cf0fa300898f3890e8ec4440005d7d9)

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
import { auth } from 'firebase/firebase-auth';
```